# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A very simple Question, but still couldn't find any answer.

I need a Rewrite Condition for all cases. I don't care If the directory, the file or any of that exists or not. Just go right to the rewrite rule.

Here is what I have:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The rule only applies for non existing files. But I want to get whatever the user typed in, because the url-string is handled with php which decides what to do with it.

**EDIT** =============================================================================

The question got answered, but it turns out this was not what I needed. So here the new modified Question:

The whole website runs on Ajax. Meaning, there is only one single index.php file, which contains the frame of the website. Every other page/content gets loaded in via Ajax. Therefore there is a folder called "pages", which contains all the content php files which get loaded into index.php.
To make this system work, I needed to make:

1. catch the input a user enters in the url through .htaccess
2. pass the input-string to php, which tries to understand where the user wants to go, and passes the address to javascript
3. javascript loads the content with ajax.

some code:

.htaccess - see above

php:

```
$pass = $_GET['url'];
$pass = str_replace(".php", "", $pass);
$pass = str_replace(".html", "", $pass);
$pass = str_replace("pages/", "", $pass);

$dirtest = "pages/" . $pass . ".php";
$isdir = file_exists($dirtest);

if ($pass == "") {
    $pass = "news";
}else{
    if (!$isdir){
        $pass = "pageNotFound";
    }
}
echo $pass;
```

Ajax:
This is a big file, so I don't want to spam this here, but it basically takes $pass and does some ajax load functions with it.

And here is the catch: 
When a user wants to access for ex: download page: he types in
"(site)/download". Since this particular file does not exist in this directory, .htaccess passes "download" to php, which checks if in the pages folder there is a download.php and since this is true, it passes "download" to Ajax. Ajax loads the from pages/download.php inside index.php. This is how it should be.
But what if the user types in "(site)/pages/download". .htaccess notices that this file exists in this directory and does not pass any parameter to php, which breaks everything.

What I need:
I need to somehow manipulate the url request to not allow a direct access to /pages/ but to allow the access when ajax is calling it.

If you need some more details or the explicit code, here is the GitHub repository:
[GitHub](https://github.com/Haeri/paint.net-mock-up-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based rule:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php$).*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Here `(?!index\.php$)` is a negative lookahead that will prevent rewrite rule execution if request URI is `index.php`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Seems like this is about what I need, but the site breaks with 8 error messages: [Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost/Style.css".] Any idea?

Comment: Yes that is due to `style.css` also being rewritten to `index.php`. This is due to the fact that you've removed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition that prevents real files to be rewritten.

Comment: PS: does this actually affect how resources are loaded? Because neither the style.css nor javascripts are showing up..

Comment: Ah ok I see... hmm.. then I need a way to allow everything to be loaded without rewriting except the content which is stored in a folder called pages...

Comment: ok sure that can be done in same rule. Is `/pages/` the only folder you want to exclude from rewriting?

Comment: Ok here is the big picture: I take the url request as a string, remove ".php" or ".html" and pass it to javascript, which turns the string into /pages/ + url string + .php. And i load this php file using ajax. So I need to somehow only affect the url input and not the other resource files... is this possible?

Comment: But then why would you not want `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to be there?

Comment: the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l ` part I copied from the internet... I don't really know how or why this works, but it does. The trick was that the user would input something like: "(site)/download.php" which actually doesn't exist because download.php is stored in /pages/ so because the site doesent exist the rewrite function works. But as soon one types in "(site)/pages/download.php" everything breaks because this directory exists.

Comment: I think I know what I need: Everything that does not exist or if it accesses inside the /pages/ folder needs to go through the rewriteRule.

Comment: Wait, does the rewriteCondition also affect the ajax load call? Because if so, it would be impossible to achieve what I need...

Comment: Yes these rules affect AJAX requests also. But if you want to skip all `/pages/` requests then that can be done. Is this you want?

Comment: I wrote this solution: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pages/` which should rewrite if request not found or if request goes in /pages/, but now the site content is empty because the ajax cant reach the /pages/... This is a nightmare... I have no clue how I should go about this. I need a way to allow ajax access to /pages/ without rewriting...

Comment: I am not clear on how you're making AJAX requests and where your css, js files are. If you edit your question and provide all details like your AJAX, css, JS URLs then I can suggest something.

Comment: Ok I have updated the OP and added a link to GitHub so you can take a closer look at it. Thanks for sticking around and helping out. I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: You wrote: `But what if the user types in "(site)/pages/download". .htaccess notices that this file exists in this directory` How is that true since actual file is `/pages/download.php` instead of `/pages/download` ?

Comment: see php code. I remove .php/.html if existing and add a ".php" at the end.

Comment: Yes I saw that but PHP code comes **after** `mod_rewrite` rules. Can your users also enter: `/pages/download.php` ?

Comment: Yes because the ending (.html/.php) gets removed and then added again.